# "Oh, for Pete's sake!"

Tags: etymology, expressions

Just curious as to where this expression came from and when it came into being. It's one that is commonly used (among other variations, e.g. "Oh for crying out loud!"), but where does it come from originally?

Comment: A classic blasphemous curse, subverted into decency by crying out to St Peter, perhaps?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Etymonline [says](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=Pete%27s+sake&searchmode=none)

> *For Pete's sake* is attested from 1924, probably a euphemistic use of the disciple's name in place of Christ;

Comment: Sometimes, "for Pete's sake" is further euphamised to "for pity's sake."

Answer (score 13):

*For Pete's sake* can be found earlier than 1924.

[1903](http://www.archive.org/stream/pedagogicalsemin10provuoft#page/376/mode/2up)'s *The Pedagogical Seminary and Journal of Genetic Psychology, Vol. X.*, includes a paper called "Children's Interests in Words, Slang, Stories, Etc." by Edward Conradi.

From page 377 in a list of slang expressions used by girls:

[image: List of slang words]

Comment: Btw how did you come across this?

Comment: @Pacerier Probably by searching [Google Books](https://books.google.com/), finding something which was only available in preview, and then searching https://archive.org for the same title in full view. Sometimes https://www.hathitrust.org also has them too.